# What's happening behind the scenes when you use super()

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I'm curious to know what actually happens behind the scenes when you use `super()` to call a constructor of the super class. When an object is instantiated from the sub class, does the sub class inheret the super class object? or how does it work?

Here is my code for reference:

```
public class Bicycle {
//Declaring bicycles states
public int movSpeed = 0;
public int cadence = 0;
public int curGear = 0;

//Class constructor
public Bicycle(){
}

//Class constructor with params
public Bicycle(int movSpeed, int cadence, int curGear) {
    this.movSpeed = movSpeed;
    this.cadence = cadence;
    this.curGear = curGear;
}
```

Subclass:

```
public class mountainBike extends Bicycle {
//Declare mountainBikes states
public int frontTravel = 0;
public int rearTravel = 0;
public int gearMult = 0;

//Class constructor
public mountainBike(){
}

//Class constructor with params
public mountainBike(int movSpeed, int cadence, int curGear, int frontTravel, int rearTravel,int gearMult){
    super(movSpeed,cadence,curGear);
    this.frontTravel = frontTravel;
    this.rearTravel = rearTravel;
    this.gearMult = gearMult;
}
```

Comment: Technically your `mountainBike` (please use [UpperCamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) for classes) is a `Bicycle`, invoking `super(args...)` tells you that specific constructor is invoked. If you do not invoke `super()` with or without args the default constructor will be called.

Comment: I assume you are fairly new to Java so I'd also like to point out [primitive default values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), there is no real reason to set the value of `frontTravel`, `rearTravel` etc. to `0`, as that is done automatically.

Comment: Check _Head First Java_ for reference (9th chapter, ["The role of superclass constructors in an object’s life"](http://tinyurl.com/usingSuper)).

Answer (score 5):

There is no super object and subclass object. It's just ***one object*** with fields declared in the subclass in addition to fields possibly inherited from the parent class.

When `super` is invoked, the JVM invokes the constructor of the parent class to initialize the fields inherited from the parent class. Behind the scenes the constructor translates to a JVM instruction called `<init>` that assigns values to the fields.

So intuitively you you can think of it as something like:

```
public mountainBike(int movSpeed, int cadence, int curGear, int frontTravel, int rearTravel,int gearMult) {
    // an object is created here
    // call the super constructor special method <init> 
    // which initializes  the inherited fields movSpeed, cadence, and curGear
    // initialize the below fields
    this.frontTravel = frontTravel;
    this.rearTravel = rearTravel;
    this.gearMult = gearMult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers! I just want to leave a [resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) I came across that explains this pretty well for anyone viewing this question.

> We have seen that an object is of the data type of the class from
>   which it was instantiated. For example, if we write
>
> public MountainBike myBike = new MountainBike(); then myBike is of
>   type MountainBike.
>
> MountainBike is descended from Bicycle and Object. Therefore, a
>   MountainBike is a Bicycle and is also an Object, and it can be used
>   wherever Bicycle or Object objects are called for.
>
> The reverse is not necessarily true: a Bicycle may be a MountainBike,
>   but it isn't necessarily. Similarly, an Object may be a Bicycle or a
>   MountainBike, but it isn't necessarily.